# How to associate user control to Hover Button?

Tags: c#, xaml, kinect

I have the following user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Kimect.Controls.ElementControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kimect"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="50" Height="50" SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged">
    <Grid Name="mainGrid" MouseLeftButtonUp="element_MouseLeftButtonUp" Style="{StaticResource elementGrid}" >                
        <TextBlock Name="Number" Text="1" FontSize="15"  Margin="0 0 2 0" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Name="symbol" Text="H"  FontSize="20"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now I want to click on it with Kinect. I've researched and found KinectHoverButton.cs, but I have no clue how to associate the user control to the HoverButton. I'm on Kinect SDK 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a side note, Kinect SDK 1.8 is the latest version and does support many new features.  If it is possible for you to update to the latest SDK I would suggest looking into it.  Among the changes is how you interact with buttons -- replacing the "hover" with a much more intuitive "press" action.

For your `KinectHoverButton`, I'm assuming you are using the one in the "ControlBasics-WPF" example.

The `KinectHoverButton` is a subclass of `KinectButtonBase`, which is turn is a subclass of a regular `ButtonBase` class.  Here is link to the `ButtonBase` class on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase(v=vs.95).aspx

Finally, from the above link you'll notice that `ButtonBase` is a subclass of `ContentControl`:

```
public abstract class ButtonBase : ContentControl
```

... and you can put (just about) anything inside a `ContentControl`.

You will not want to ram your `UserControl` into a `KinectHoverButton`.  Instead you want to create a `KinectHoverButton` that looks like your `UserControl`, and behaves as it should when using a gesture environment.  You can create a `UserControl` that contains just a single `KinectHoverButton` if you want to reuse it.

As a simple example:

```
<KinectHoverButton>
  <Grid>                
    <TextBlock Name="Number" Text="1" FontSize="15"  Margin="0 0 2 0" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Name="symbol" Text="H"  FontSize="20"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>
</KinectHoverButton>
```

... will create a Kinect enabled button that looks very close (you'll have to play with styling a little bit) to your existing `UserControl`.